# Symfony how check is checkox is checked without form

Tags: php, post, symfony

Can send data with POST without form. I have list of elements in my view like this

```
<li><p>{{contents.1}}</p>
    <a href="{{ path('set_visit', {'start': contents.0  }) }}">Zapisz wizyte</a>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">
    I have a car 
</li>
```

After click  tag I go to the controller. Can I in my controller check is checkbox is checked or didn't ? I use Symfony2

Comment: How did you create this form? In the controller, or just via html?

Comment: I don't want create form, I have a few li tag like above. I asked is way to check this checkbox without use a form

Answer (score 0):

The point is that only checked values are sent to your controller while others are not. You need to build the list of all possible options in your controller method, then subtract submitted ones to get list of all unchecked options **OR** use submitted list to determine if it was checked...

Did I get your problem right?